# Create plot and save it in .NET Core console app, without view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, charts, oxyplot

There was a need to draw a beautiful chart from the data on the backend and send it as file\stream. The view is not needed, there is nowhere to display it on the backend.

Suddenly I was faced with the fact that as if there were no libraries for this. There is a lot for the front, chart.js  for excample but for the backend it seems not.

There are libraries for drawing, such as ImageSharp, but graphics using them are inconvenient to draw, you will have to write a wrapper.

OxyPlot - there are no examples for backing in the documentation, only for WPF, Xamarin, Silverlight, etc. - in general, for platforms with views.

There is some package in NuGet OxyPlot.ImageSharp, which seems to be a wrapper over ImageSharp, but there is no documentation on it.

```
var Plot = new PlotController();
var model = new PlotModel();
    
OxyPlot.ImageSharp.ImageRenderContext context = new ImageRenderContext(200,200,OxyColor.FromArgb(1,1,1,1));

context.SaveAsBmp();
```

It can be seen that I can get the context for rendering. And this context can be saved to a file.

But how to connect the model, controller, and generally fill the graph with data?

Therefore, the question is a bit general - how to make a beautiful graph in the .NETCore console application, and save it to a file \ stream? Or, in case I'm digging in the right direction - how to work with this library?

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot. The link is on the NuGet Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i did it:

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.ImageSharp;
using OxyPlot.Series;
// ...    
var model = new PlotModel { Title = "Plot", Background = OxyColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255) };
model.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Sin, 0d, 10d, 0.1, "Sin(x)"));
PngExporter.Export(model, "plot.png", 1280, 720);
```